# Error : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Source Error:

```
{
   DateTime registrationDate = Convert.ToDateTime(frmclientcollection["regdate"].ToString());
   DateTime ContractPeriod = Convert.ToDateTime(frmclientcollection["ContractPeriod"].ToString());
   var clientModel = new ClientRegistration()
   {
   }
}
```

This is error I'm getting while converting `string` to `DateTime`.
The names of fields are perfectly right, as written in view.
Please provide a solution.

Comment: Well, what are the values you're passing to `ToDateTime()`? What is your culture setting?

Comment: What is the data type of frmclientcollection["regdate"]?  If it is `DateTime`, why are you converting to `string` and then _back_ to `DateTime`?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using DateTime.Tryparse:

```
   string strToParse = "04-02-2013";
           DateTime result;
           if(!DateTime.TryParse(strToParse, out result))
           {
             string error = strToParse+ " is not a valid date";
   }
```

Most likely the problem is " frmclientcollection["ContractPeriod"] " does not returning the string you expected.

Comment: also you should properly add the C# tag to your question

Comment: How is that going to help? Why would `DateTime.TryParse()` work if `Convert.ToDateDTime()` didn't?

Comment: @svick, Per the [MSDN documentation for Convert.ToDateTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e.aspx), "If you prefer not to handle an exception if the conversion fails, you can call the DateTime.TryParse method instead. It returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the conversion succeeded or failed."

Comment: @EdmundSchweppe But the question is not “How to avoid the exception?”, it's “How to get the date?” (At least I assume it is, the question is not very clear about that.)

Comment: @svick, as near as I could tell, the OP's question was how to avoid the exception. (As you say, however, it's not very clear.)